# I'm unable to use @font-face Support on my wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

```
/*
@font - face {
    font - family: 'MVFaseyha';
    src: url('http://www.mvyouth.mv/live/wp-content/themes/mvyouth_2013/stylesheets/fonts/MVFaseyha.otf') format('truetype');
    font - weight: normal;
    font - style: normal;
} */
```

This is the code I'm using to embed fonts. I'm using a  Dhivehi language (Maldivian) font, which include unicode chars* I guess. I don't know much about CSS etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is with the src path. It depends where your fonts folder is located but it should probably be something like `src: url(../fonts/MVFaseyha.otf')` if your @font-face statement is in your css file also located in stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

FF (and perhaps other browsers) prevent loading font files from a different domain.

See this answer for details: [CSS @font-face absolute URL from external domain: fonts not loading in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616306/css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox)

You can always download the font files you need and load them locally.  Just hit the url in your font-face call and it should download.

Answer (score 0):

A complete tutorial, specifically about icon fonts, but same basic approach: http://gomakethings.com/icon-fonts/