# css as assets font embedding won't work on firefox

Tags: css, fonts

I am building a website that serve the assets (image, css, javascript) from a subdomain inside the same server, everything works fine except Firefox doesn't seem to render the fonts i am embedding

my css (on assets.mydomain.dev)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('http://assets.mydomain.dev/fonts/awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0');
  src: url('http://assets.mydomain.dev/fonts/awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('http://assets.mydomain.dev/fonts/awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'), 
       url('http://assets.mydomain.dev/fonts/awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'), 
       url('http://assets.mydomain.dev/fonts/awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.1.0') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

htaccess (on assets.mydomain.dev)

```
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType font/ttf .ttf
    AddType font/otf .otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff woff

    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

folder structure (on assets.mydomain.dev)

```
/
    /fonts
        /awesome
            /fontawesome-webfont.eot
            /fontawesome-webfont.woff
            /fontawesome-webfont.ttf
            /fontawesome-webfont.svg
```

i have been looking into some "how to" here in stackoverflow, such as these

[css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616306/css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox)

[css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

but none seems to work, please help me

Comment: So you tried the solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11616436/1016716) but it didn't seem to work? What happened? Did you get errors?

Comment: @MrLister i am using the font-awesome for the icons, it doesn't give me errors but the icons doesn't show, like it does on chrome