# Buttons not showing correctly (Videojs font not working on subdomain)

Tags: font-face, video.js, access-control

I'm having problems with video.js. On the main domain everthings works fine. But on the www. subdomain the buttons are not showing correctly (It's just showing ).

It looks like the font doesn't work on the subdomain. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Could you link us to a live example, or a JSFiddle?

Comment: Not working: http://bit.ly/1bIJLMU
Working: http://bit.ly/15cs5Ys

I'm using FF 24.

Comment: Aha, the trap of cross-domain custom firefox fonts! Answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VideoJS uses a custom font, defined using the `@font-face` directive in video-js.css. The paths defined inside are relative. When FireFox goes to load the fonts, it uses the root URL of the CSS file and concatenates the font paths.

The custom fonts are thus being loaded from your main domain when viewing the subdomain. Doesn't sound like a problem, right? But **Firefox [does not allow cross-domain fonts without access control headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616306/css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox)** for security.

In other words, FireFox normally requires every custom font to be loaded from the domain of the page that's showing. If you're viewing *www.example.com*, your fonts have to come from *www.example.com*, not *example.com*.

You can either

1. Use the solution linked above to add the appropriate headers to your server (if you have control) to allow the "cross-domain" fonts (www.example.com is considered a different domain from example.com)
2. Load the VideoJS CSS file dynamically from whichever domain is active.

If you want to go the latter route, when the user's viewing `www.example.com`, load `http://*www.*example.com/path/to/video-js/video-js.min.css`. When viewing `example.com`, load `http://example.com/path/to/video-js/video-js.min.css`.

Note that Webkit doesn't care -- seems to just be a Firefox problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I have converted the absolute links into relative ones. Simple solution and it works fine! (Can you just do me a favour and replace the domain throught a dummy? I don't want this question under the google search results for the webpage.)

Comment: Cool. Changed to example.com.

Answer (score 0):

*Apply this css and get output*

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'VideoJS';
    src: url('https://vjs.zencdn.net/f/1/vjs.eot');
    src: url('https://vjs.zencdn.net/f/1/vjs.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
      url('https://vjs.zencdn.net/f/1/vjs.woff') format('woff'),     
      url('https://vjs.zencdn.net/f/1/vjs.ttf') format('truetype');
  }

.video-js .vjs-play-control.vjs-playing .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .vjs-icon-pause:before {
    content: "\f103";
    font-family: 'VideoJS';
}

.video-js .vjs-mute-control .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .vjs-icon-volume-high:before {
    content: "\f107";
    font-family: 'VideoJS';
}

.video-js .vjs-big-play-button .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .video-js .vjs-play-control .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .vjs-icon-play:before {
    content: "\f101";
    font-family: 'VideoJS';
}

.video-js .vjs-picture-in-picture-control .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .vjs-icon-picture-in-picture-enter:before {
    content: "\f121";
    font-family: 'VideoJS';
}



 .video-js .vjs-fullscreen-control .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .vjs-icon-fullscreen-enter:before {
    content: "\f108";
    font-family: 'VideoJS';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me when the icons were rendering blank:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: VideoJS;
    src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```