# Font not displayed in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I am using a `@font-face` - as recommended, I use `.eot`, `.woff`, `.ttf` and `.svg`. It appears normally except in Firefox, where it is not used and falls back to Helvetica / sans-serif.

Normal:

[image: normal]

Firefox:

[image: firefox]

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/LREnbhzla/lato-thin.eot');
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/LREnbhzla/lato-thin.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/iQinbhzmp/lato-thin.woff') format('woff'), url('http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/Lxynbhzok/lato-thin.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/p2Anbj1jl/lato-thin.svg') format('svg');
}

h1 { 
    font-family: "Lato", "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", "Helvetica Neue UltraLight", sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
     }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>title</h1>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yghk8d1a/1/)

How can we fix this?

I saw some similar questions suggest using local links for fonts but I can't use it here.

Comment: That's most likely due to firefox's origin policy. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11616436/301596

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the console log in Firefox, it has entries like this:

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Lato" style:normal weight:900 stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://static.tumblr.com/cv6ot7o/iQinbhzmp/lato-thin.woff

So apparently the site wants to disallow remote use of their fonts.

Consider using [Lato at Google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato) instead.

Indepenendly of this, it is very illogical to declare Lato Thin as having weight 900. It is declared as having weight 100. You should use `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet'>` and `h1 { font-family: Lato; font-weight: 100 }`.

Comment: thanks- but I'm not allowed to use external resources for this project, any other ideas?

Comment: @ValKalinic, isn’t static.tumblr.com an external resource? Anyway, you can download the font file from the Google site, process it with the Fontsquirrel `@font-face` generator, upload the resulting files onto your server, and use suitable relative links.

Comment: yes, those are the ones I included in the question, static.tumblr.com is the hosting allowed and somelink.tumblr.com/ is the website url

Comment: @ValKalinic, it is then cross-site access, since “site” in this context relates to the server name; static.tumblr.com and somelink.tumblr.com are two different servers. The previous advice still applies: use fonts hosted by a service that allows cross-site access or use fonts uploaded onto the same server as your pages.

Comment: again I'm not allowed -and all other browsers have no problem with it