# Different stylesheets links not working?

Tags: css

So I wanted a custom glyphicon and used icomoon to do so. Instead of importing the entire library to the server, I simply used a stylesheet import to make things easier.

Now the stylesheet on icomoon only allowed the style.css link to be open for 24 hours, so I simply took the contents of the style.css file and put it on a custom domain.

Old style.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/8e91637825/UntitledProject/style.css">
```

New style.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://thecommentsection.co.uk/style.css">
```

This is the contents of the style.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:    url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/8e91637825/UntitledProject/icomoon.eot?kxcvpn');
    src:    url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/8e91637825/UntitledProject/icomoon.eot?kxcvpn#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/8e91637825/UntitledProject/icomoon.ttf?kxcvpn') format('truetype'),
        url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/8e91637825/UntitledProject/icomoon.woff?kxcvpn') format('woff'),
        url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/8e91637825/UntitledProject/icomoon.svg?kxcvpn#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-rubyit:before {
    content: "\1f4a3";
}
```

### The Issue

The only thing I changed on the stylesheet import is the href link, but for some reason changing the link from the old to new suddenly stops the glyphicon from working?

Any ideas?

Comment: On what domain are you running it? It looks like a CORS issue.

Comment: well, did you check? :/

Comment: Yeah, no console errors came up :|

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616306/css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox)?

Comment: One link is https, the other is http. Definitely look into that.

Comment: Both the secure connection and @font-face are the issues that are apparently occurring. Thanks all.