# failed download status in chrome(net::ERR_FAILED) for fonts and 206 in firefox but it dosen't apply in any of them

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

i have a page styled lik:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="http://mydomain.ir/fonts/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

and in `style.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GanjNamehSans-Regular';
    src: url("GanjNamehSans-Regular.otf");
    src: url("GanjNamehSans-Regular.otf?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
     url("GanjNamehSans-Regular.woff") format('woff'), url("GanjNamehSans-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

   body {
            font-family: 'GanjNamehSans-Regular';
            direction: rtl;
            width: 100%;
            color:white;
            background-color: #383434;
            text-align:center;

        }
```

but this font not applied to body or anywhere i try to use. i checked network tab in inspect in chrome and firefox. in network tab filtered fonts and in chrome status is `failed` and in firefox status is `206`... but not working

when try to open links font will be downloaded...

### update:

i did the following but still have this error :`**net::ERR_FAILED**`

1. clear cache
2. Open the page in an Incognito window
3. Clear your cache and cookies
4. Close other tabs, extensions, & apps

Comment: Hi, have you been able to find the root-cause and resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue for my own font hosted in AWS, i.e. ERR_FAILED in Chrome and 206 in Firefox.

Upon checking, it could be a standard CORS issue where you are trying to access resources from another domain. There are few solutions posted in Stack Overflow for fonts hosted by different web servers, eg: [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616306/css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox) and [Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx).

In my case in AWS, I have to set the CORS settings for the S3 bucket hosting my font with the following:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

You can tweak the `AllowedOrigins` to the sites that are importing the font accordingly.